# Plot on reciprocity scale in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot like the one schematized below with x-axis on a reciprocal scale and y-axis on a profit scale, ideally with ggplot2 but I haven't figured out a way to do that. Is there anyone who could help me? [image]

Comment: As you have mentioned **ggplot**: you could use something like `scale_y_continuous(trans='log2')`  with possible values for trans : 'log2', 'log10','sqrt'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scales` package to transform scales, functions `reciprocal_trans()` and `probit_trans()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(trans = reciprocal_trans()) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = probit_trans())
```